# How to define static init block outside classes in Kotlin?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

I have utility file **Utility.kt**

Here I have defined some constants like

```
val DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
const val UTC_TIMEZONE = "UTC"
```

Now I need to define list with 2 elements. I can't find a way to write it in static way. I need something like

```
val DEFAULT_LIST = ArrayList<MyObj>()
val one = MyObj("one")
val two = MyObj("two")
DEFAULT_LIST.addAll(one,two)
```

i.e. To Create list and objects only once. I can use companion object. But right now I just use file without classes.

Is it possible?

Comment: [`arrayListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most general solution is calling `run`, which takes no parameters and results in the value that is the result of the block. With minimum changes to your code:

```
val DEFAULT_LIST = run {
    val it = ArrayList<MyObj>()
    val one = MyObj("one")
    val two = MyObj("two")
    it.add(one)
    it.add(two)
    it
}
```

Comment: How can you call `run` at top level? Wouldn't it be better to create the list and call `apply` on it? Also, calling a local variable `it` inside a lambda is somewhat confusing :$

Comment: For the exact code OP posted, neither `run` nor `apply` is the most elegant approach, but simply `listOf(MyObj("one"), MyObj("two"))`. However, I chose to look through the minimal example and suggest the most general construct, one which doesn't assume things like that you can create the resulting instance on the first line.

Comment: I agree that in this case, `listOf()` is sufficient, and that the OP is clearly asking more generally how to initialize stuff on the fly. However, even if the `run` approach *is* the most general, I believe `apply` can be used in most cases (object creation + setters/init), so it should be worth noting that `run` is almost never necessary. Btw, I just learnt a top level `run` existed, I only knew about the `T.run()`, so thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create the list with `listOf` or `arrayListOf` and parameters:

```
val DEFAULT_LIST = listOf(MyObj("one"),MyObj("two"))
```

Or if you really need a more complex object creation, e.g. `ArrayList`, use the scope function [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) or [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) for initialization.
Both return the receiver (this) and you can assign it to a variable:

```
val DEFAULT_LIST = ArrayList<MyObj>().apply {
    val one = MyObj("one")
    val two = MyObj("two")
    one.complicatedProperty("complicated_property")
    two.complicatedProperty("complicated_property")


    add(one)
    add(two)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, the usual way is with the `listOf()` function.

If you don't need to keep individual references to the two objects, you can just do:

```
val DEFAULT_LIST = listOf(MyObj("one"), MyObj("two"))
```

Or if you do:

```
val one = MyObj("one")
val two = MyObj("two")
val DEFAULT_LIST = listOf(one, two)
```

If you want more control over the exact type of list, you can use `mutableListOf()`, or `arrayListOf()`, or call a constructor that takes a collection of items (e.g. `LinkedList(listOf(one, two))`).

Comment: How to do in case of complicated MyObj cration. If i need to use setters?